# can't copy image from asset folder to sdcard

Tags: android, android-sdcard, android-assets

I'm trying to copy a valid image (jpg) from asset folder to the sdcard. 
I have Write permissions on the manifest(and read). 
This is the function i use, and giving it the "image.jpg" as listed in the asset folder. 
When i go to the path of the external storage directory, i can see that the copy was made, and that there's an "image.jpg" file, however, it's not a valid image, since i can't open it.

```
private void copyFile(String fileName)
{
    try
    {
        File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + fileName);
        if (f.exists())
        {
            return;
        }
        InputStream in = getResources().getAssets().open(fileName);
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + fileName);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int read;
        while ((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1)
        {
            out.write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
        in.close();
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        Toast.makeText(/* getActivity() */this, "Failed to copy file: " + fileName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

any help will be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: did you put the write permssion in the manifest?

Comment: Are you doing this with the emulator or a device ?

Comment: Does the image copied have a non zero size ?

Comment: check the file sizes, whether they are same or not ?

Comment: In the 1st line, i wrote that i put the permissions in the manifest. run on real device, image is valid, as i stated. file sizes are the same.

Comment: I have added your code in my application and same worked for me. What is the size of your image?

Comment: does it ? now it's just wired then.. file size is almost 2MB.

Comment: I tried for 1.87 MB and its working.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my sample code (copy Assets folder to Storage folder)

```
public boolean copyAssetToStorage(final Activity activity, final String from, final String to) {

        final AssetManager assetManager = activity.getAssets();

        final File outDir;
        if ( TextUtils.isEmpty(to) ) {
            outDir = rootFile;
        } else {
            outDir = new File(rootFile, to);
            outDir.mkdir();
        }

//      if (TextUtils.isEmpty(from)) {
//          new RuntimeException("From Path is Empty String.").printStackTrace();
//          return false;
//      }
        if (from == null) {
            new RuntimeException("From Path is Null String.").printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }

        final String[] assets;
        try {
            assets = assetManager.list(from);
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            LogUtil.e("AssetManager.list() 에러");
            e1.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }

        Thread copyThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                for (String fileName : assets) {
                    InputStream is;
                    FileOutputStream fos;
                    LogUtil.i("복사 시작: "+fileName); // Copy Start!
                    try {
                        is = assetManager.open(from+File.separator+fileName);
                        int size = is.available();
                        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
                        File outFile = new File(outDir, fileName);
                        fos = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
                        for (int c = is.read(buffer); c != -1; c=is.read(buffer)) {
                            fos.write(buffer, 0, c);
                        }
                        is.close();
                        fos.close();
                    } catch (IOException e2) {
                        e2.printStackTrace();
                        return;
                    }
                    LogUtil.i("복사 완료: "+fileName); // Completed!!!
                }

            }
        }, "CopyThread");

        copyThread.start();

        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Other way that you can put your image in res -> raw folder
This code can copy all file to sdcard from your res -> raw folder

```
    java.lang.reflect.Field[] fields=R.raw.class.getFields();
    for(int count=0; count < fields.length; count++){
        try { 
            int resourceID=fields[count].getInt(fields[count]);
            InputStream in = getResources().openRawResource(resourceID);
            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/"+fields[count].getName()+".png");
            byte[] buf = new byte[2048];
            int len;
            while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
                out.write(buf, 0, len);
            }   
            in.close(); 
            out.close();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```